# Keep submenu open after hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Website is [Mariodidit.com](http://www.mariodidit.com)

When hovering over "Portfolio" there is a submenu that appears. 
However, if you do move the mouse directly over the center item, the menu just disappears, making it frustrating to navigate. I would like to use some javascript to keep it open after hovering "Portfolio"

```
$('.main-navigation li ul li a').hide();
$('.main-navigation').live('hover', function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('activeitem');
  $('.main-navigation li ul li a').show();
});
```

Ive tried a few different code snippets like this and have made no progress.
Also using "Header and Footer scripts" plugin to apply this script to my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use on click instead of hover.

```
(function($) {
    $('.main-navigation li a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then in CSS add styles for that class.

```
.main-navigation .active ul {
    display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul ul { 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: tried it and it didnt seem to work.
even tried different id/class combinations :/

Comment: I modified the logic a bit, try again.

Comment: still nothing, is it possible that I am calling the wrong class/id?

Comment: Mariodidit.com appears to be running jQuery in no conflict mode. Therefore you'll need to replace all instances of $ with jQuery.

Comment: Can I follow these steps to use the coding you provided?
https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: You can wrap it in a self invoking anonymous function and pass jQuery.  I'll update the answer for you.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but unfortunately I cannot get this to work. I must have something conflicting with the code, or Im calling to the wrong class. ".main-navigation" and it should be something else?